# how insert data to google calendar from my website with php

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a schedule.
I'll entry data (schedule) on my website and I want this schedule will be saved on my google calendar with php.

I was read Google calendar API, but i still don't understand mechanism of it.
Who can help me resolve it? Or You can give a demo about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us, where you get stuck and we might could help you. Until this question is to unspecific for any good answer.

Comment: @frlan I want insert data to my google calendar from my website. But i don't know mechanism of google calendar.
I need who can give me a demo insert data to google calendar or document guide i make it.
I was see API google calendar but i still don't understand. I need a demo to understand it.
Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Just googled it: "php google calendar api example"